# Untitle file issue at google drive when using curl API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, filenames, php-curl

When I try to upload file at google drive using php curl API it is giving untitled. ANd I can't show file name. How can I properly upload file using curl php? I don't want to use client libraries.There is not file title of uploaded file at google drive

```
function save_application_form($wpcf7) {

//global $wpdb;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
        $submited = array();
        $submited['title'] = $wpcf7->title();
        $submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
    }
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $cf7_file_field_name = 'file-846';
    $image_location = $uploaded_files[$cf7_file_field_name];
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $image_location);
    $token = GetRefreshedAccessToken('client_id', 'refresh_token', 'client_secret');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type:' . $mime_type,
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents($image_location),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: File is uploaded at google drive but it is untitled. Not showing file name

Comment: Is there anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You are not uploading the metadata of the file you are only uploading the file itself.  THe [post body](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) needs to include the file metadata the filename being one of those items.

**Offical php client library example**

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) shows how to do this with googles client library.

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg'));
$content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

**PHP CURL wild guess**

Sorry i cant help you do this in curl.  But it should just be a matter of sending the post body as a JSon string containing the data you wish.  The following is my best guess after some Googling.

```
$data = array("name" => "picture.jpg", "mimeType"=> "image/jpeg");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

Comment: Right, but I want to get using curl

Comment: Yup you need to send the metadata as the post body.    Your going to have to figure out how to do that in Curl.   All i can do is tell you whats wrong.   I posted a guess that i got form Googling php curl and post body.  It might be close

Comment: This is still giving untitled. What can I do?

Comment: the only thing you can do is upload the meta data to the file.  once you have done that it won't be until anymore